# OpenCV stream captured CAM with H264 (mp4) codec

Tags: opencv, stream, ffmpeg, live555

I like to stream the web cam pictures wich are captured by opencv. I think about a solution with ffmpeg and live555 (poorly they are not document so well). My problems are:

1. How can convert the captured images to a H264 format so the picures/second match. If it is in a loop I get more than 25 pictures/sekond and the video is to fast.
2. How can i directly stream the converted H264 stream over the network via rtp / rtps or similar.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

1. This is a common problem.

   - if you are not require to distribute your software (private use / server side / open-source), you may use [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) compiled with [x264 encoder](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html), there's a config flag for that in FFMpeg's config script.
   - If you do require to distribute your software, i don't know any LGPL licensed library for that, i believe there is no such library. You'd have to use some paid solution.
2. You should implement DeviceSource.cpp, see DeviceSource.hh and use it as the FramedSource.

**Edit**: Apple revealed video encoder API, allowing access to stream of h264 frames in iOS8

Answer (score 1):

For an example of how to use x264 and Live555 to encode and stream frames, see the following:

1. [spyPanda](https://code.launchpad.net/~alex-stevens/+junk/spyPanda) open source project.
2. [How to write a Live555 FramedSource to allow me to stream H.264 live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863673/how-to-write-a-live555-framedsource-to-allow-me-to-stream-h-264-live/14121172#14121172) SO question.