# RTSP server on live555 start send client on I-Frame (h264)

Tags: h.264, rtsp, live555

I wrote a simple rtsp server using live555. I took most of the code from here [Live555: X264 Stream Live source based on "testOnDemandRTSPServer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427576/live555-x264-stream-live-source-based-on-testondemandrtspserver#answer-21412719)

When a new client connects, it begins to receive packets from the one that currently came from the encoder. This can be a P-frame and an I-frame. How can I make sure that when connected, the client starts receiving data only from the I-frame?

Comment: You need to store the whole Last GOP like last I-Frame and followed P,B frames. But this would then mean your Receiver is behind these frames. Better to skip the frames on receiver side and start decoding from first recv. I-frame

Comment: Yes, it’s better to skip this on the client side. But I need to do this on the server. It is not necessary to store the GOP, I thought when connecting a client to skip sending frames to it until I encounter the first I-frame. I don't know where exactly to track this in FramedSource or RTPSink or somewhere else

Comment: Ok check out my answer, in short u need to determine nal_unit_type by inspecting the NAL Unit.

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the nal unit type, based on your requierements i think deliverFrame would be good, i dont check the whole code but nal unit have information about the frame Type.

Look Here for more Infos [H264 Nal Unit](https://yumichan.net/video-processing/video-compression/introduction-to-h264-nal-unit/) you can identify the I-Frame by **Coded slice of an IDR picture**

```
void LiveSourceWithx264::deliverFrame()
{
    if(!isCurrentlyAwaitingData() || nalQueue.empty()) return;

    x264_nal_t nal = nalQueue.front();
    // Extract the NAL unit type
    int nalType = nal.p_payload[4] & 0x1F; // Assuming 4-byte start code

    // Check if we're looking for the first I-frame
    if (firstFrame && nalType != 5) {
        nalQueue.pop(); // Discard non-I-frames at the beginning
        return; // Skip until we find an I-frame
    }

    firstFrame = false; // Reset flag after finding the first I-frame

    // Existing logic to handle frame delivery
    nalQueue.pop();
    ...
}
```

Comment: LiveSourceWithx264 is the source of frames for all clients, if I drop frames in this code it will be dropped frames for all clients, and also there is no information about connected clients from here

Comment: OK then checking nal units where it send to a New client